# How to express p[t] as a function of S[t]?

Tags: differential-equations

Profit[t_] := p[t]*(D0 - [Alpha]*p[t]) - [Sigma]*S[t]

- D[S[t],t] = d[t] =D0 - [Alpha]*p[t]
  How can I let mathematica express p[t] as a function of S[t] and therefore simplify Profit[t] into a function containing S[t], D0, Alpha, Sigma, and probably S'[t] (but without p[t])?

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

rule = Solve[D[S[t], t] == D0 - α*p[t], p[t]][[1]]

(* {p[t] -> (D0 - Derivative[1][S][t])/α} *)

Profit[t_] = p[t]*(D0 - α*p[t]) - σ*S[t] /. rule

(* -σ S[t] + ((D0 - Derivative[1][S][t]) Derivative[1][S][t])/α *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
rule2 = D[S[t] -> ((t - T) (-4 S0 + t T α σ))/(4 T), 
   t] // Simplify

(* Derivative[1][S][t] -> -(S0/T) + 1/4 (2 t - T) α σ *)

Optimalp[t_] = ((D0 - D[S[t], t])/α /. rule2) // Expand // 
  FullSimplify

(* (S0 + D0 T)/(T α) + 1/4 (-2 t + T) σ *)
```

Comment: I used exactly the Solve code but my result is {p[t] -> D0/\[Alpha]}; and it may say "Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of p[t]->D0/\[Alpha]", may I know what my problem is?

Comment: Did you `Clear` your variables first to remove prior definitions? Or start with a fresh kernel.

Comment: Ohh thank you so much!